# how to make sure run website with javascript disabled

Tags: java, javascript, spring, architecture, frameworks

Our website UI is build in javaScript, JQuery. Lots of task is performed by jquery. UI doing lots of filter , sorting searching , tabular display.

Now we want to make sure that web site works fine even javascript is disabled on browser?

SPRING MVC <>

can any body give me idea how can we achieve this?

Can any other technology will do over it?

can GWT will be able to achieve this ?

Comment: Well I don't particularly think this question deserves a down vote. All of us want to see if there's a better solution than what we thought of. So upping it to 0.

Comment: I think this is not the best approach. If you want to develop a Web able to work without JS (lets say AA), first, you should develop it without JS. One it is done, add JS to improve UI.

Comment: the term you are looking for is "progressive enhancement"

Answer (score 2):

If your website is built using JavaScript technology itself, then unless you build it WITHOUT JavaScript, there is no way you can achieve this.

Answer (score 0):

GWT is out because it basically compile some Java-ish code into javascript. With spring MVC, you can **rewrite** your site to use only clients view (JSP) and server side actions (MVC controllers) for sorting, ...

Answer (score 0):

What you were supposed to do with your particular requirement was to build a basic site that worked without JavaScript and then use JavaScript to make it much more whizzbang(Pretty with cool effects)!! :-D But since you have already built the site the only solution I can think off the top of my head is to crate a new basic site with HTML and make it the default site. From that basic you can check if JavaScript is enabled and then redirect the user to the whizzbang site(JavaScript enabled one) with a simple JavaScript redirect!

Answer (score 0):

Some sites can degrade gracefully from a faster, slicker version that uses JS, to another that does not.  Unfortunately that does not seem the case with your site.

One strategy is to define a redirect in HTML (should be set for 5-10 seconds<sup>1</sup>)that points to `needjs.html` that explains to the user that:

> Sorry, we do not have the ability to provide this site without JS.

In JS, cancel the redirect.

Comment: Is it we dont have any way to develop a jaggy website without javascript?

Comment: highly interactive and user attracting .

Answer (score 0):

The majority of sites now-a-days presume there's javascript.  If you want to check how your site behaves, turn off javascript in the browser.  If you want content for when javascript is disabled only, put it in a `<noscript>` tag, but be aware GoogleBot (SEO) runs without javascript, and will hit this.  How to make the site function nicely without javascript?  Build some ninja html and css and do all your work server-side.  But again, since most every site presumes javascript is enabled, users who disable it are already familiar with how broken they've made the web.  It may just be sufficient to put a `<noscript>` that includes a message about how this site requires javascript.